# access selected option value outside scope of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to access option value outside of ng-repeat scope .
here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srjahir32/ohotng3f/1/)

If you look at it, i can access id but not name. How can I access name outside scope of ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-controller="csrClrt">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Face Style:</label>
        <md-select ng-model="style" ng-change="f_style()">
            <md-option ng-value="user.id" ng:repeat="user in styles">{{user.name}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
    <div>
        Id:{{style}}
        <br/> Want to Display Name {{name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

angularJS

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('csrClrt', function ($scope) {

     stylesdata=[{name:"a",id:0},{name:"b",id:1},{name:"c",id:3}];
     var style=[];
     for(var i=0;i<stylesdata.length;i++)
     {
       style.push({
        name:stylesdata[i].name,
        id:stylesdata[i].id
       })
     }
     $scope.styles=style;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ng-value="user"` instead of `ng-value="user.id"` and add `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"` to handle deep equality:

```
<md-select ng-model="style" ng-change="f_style()" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
  <md-option ng-value="user" ng:repeat="user in styles">{{user.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ohotng3f/2/

Also, see corresponding section [in angular material documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect#selects-and-object-equality) for reference